# Multiple control types in a single GridView column

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

with: SELECT id, name, Flag1 FROM Table

Is it possible to dynamically display either a Button or a CheckBox in a single column based upon the bit value of the Flag1 field?

In other words:
If Flag1 = true then show checkbox as checked and readonly.
If Flag1 = false show Button with click event and pass id of row to handler.

Which event would i need to hook to make the change? DataBound?
How would I set up the checkbox/button in .aspx or .cs? Normally I use ItemTemplates with Gridviews...

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Under Warranty" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="WButton" runat="server" CommandName="AddWarrantyTrackerItem" CommandArgument = "<%# (Container.DataItemIndex) %>" Text="Track Warranty" Visible="false" />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="WFlag" runat="server" Visible="false" readonly="true" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Depot" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="DButton" runat="server" CommandName="AddDepotTrackerItem" CommandArgument = "<%# (Container.DataItemIndex) %>" Text="Track Depot" Visible="false" />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="DFlag" runat="server" Visible="false"  readonly="true" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

CodeBehind:

```
    protected void gridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox WFlag = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("WFlag");
        Button WButton = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("WButton");
        CheckBox DFlag = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("DFlag");
        Button DButton = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("DButton");
        var record = (System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord)e.Row.DataItem;
        bool flagW = (bool)record.GetValue(14);
        bool flagD = (bool)record.GetValue(15);
        int reqnum = (int)record.GetValue(0);
        if (flagW == false) 
        {
            WButton.Visible = true;
            WFlag.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            WButton.Visible = false;
            WFlag.Visible = true;
            WFlag.Checked = true;
        }
        if (flagD == false)   
        {
            DButton.Visible = true;
            DFlag.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            DButton.Visible = false;
            DFlag.Visible = true;
            DFlag.Checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `TemplateField` and `RowDataBound` to switch visibility :

aspx:

```
<Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Flagged">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="ButtonFlag" runat="server" Text="flag it" Visible="true" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckFlag" runat="server" Checked="true" Visible="false" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void gridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox chkFlag = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("CheckFlag");
        Button buttonFlag = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("ButtonFlag");
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        bool flagged = row.Field<bool>("Flag1");
        buttonFlag.Visible = !flagged;
        chkFlag.Visible = flagged;
    }
}
```

Comment: DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row; errors:  Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.

Comment: @user1431356: Are you now using a `DataReader` as datasource? Try `var rd = (System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord)e.Row.DataItem;`. If that works you can use the methods of [`DbDataRecord`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatarecord.aspx) to get all fields.